# Intuition for feeding output from 'row' DCT in to 'column' DCT for JPEG

Tags: dct, jpeg

This question is motivated by [23:00 in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0me3guauqOU&t=1382s).

It shows how the output from 'row' DCT is fed in to 'column' DCT for JPEG, and shows this image (*highlights are mine*):

[image: screenshot from video showing DCTs]

In the top 'Rows' row my intuition is that the rows I've highlighted green correspond to each other, to the top row in the original image.

Further it is my understanding the columns no longer map to the columns in the original image. The column highlighted blue does not correspond to the column highlighted red.

Given this I don't have any intuition **why applying a columnwise DCT is meaningful**.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The 2D DCT is an identical operation to applying a 1D DCT to both dimensions sequentially. After performing the DCT along dimension 1, there is still information along dimension 2 that can be compressed. Though it may seem unclear what information is being transformed, remember that these two DCT operations are "undone" with the 2D inverse transform so that the image can be recovered.

Comment: @Ash: That's an answer, not a comment!  Please feel free to make it so.  The only thing I'd add is that you can do a 2D rectangular DCT in _either direction_ -- aside from numerical scrud, a column-first 2D DCT gives you the same results as a row-first 2D DCT.